# Edit Coldfusion Survey Application to return one more field value

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion, cfc

I have a coldfusion survey application which I am trying to edit to return and compare ther value of a new column in the database

I have the following function in the cfc file which should return the value for the new field being "questionfiltert":

```
<cffunction name="getQuestion" access="public" returnType="struct" output="false"
            hint="Grabs a question.">
    <cfargument name="id" type="uuid" required="true" hint="The UUID of the question to get.">
    <cfset var qQuestion = "">
    <cfset var result = "">

    <cfquery name="qQuestion" datasource="#variables.dsn#">
        select  #variables.tableprefix#questions.id, surveyidfk, question, questiontypeidfk, rank, required, questionfilter, 
        #variables.tableprefix#questiontypes.name as questiontype, #variables.tableprefix#questions.nextquestion, #variables.tableprefix#questions.nextquestionvalue
        from    #variables.tableprefix#questions, #variables.tableprefix#questiontypes
        where   #variables.tableprefix#questions.id = <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.id#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" maxlength="35">
        and     #variables.tableprefix#questions.questiontypeidfk = #variables.tableprefix#questiontypes.id
    </cfquery>

    <cfset result = variables.utils.queryToStruct(qQuestion)>
    <cfset result.answers = getAnswers(arguments.id)>
    <cfreturn result>

</cffunction>
```

The code where I am trying to get

```
...<cfif allDone>

    <cfif lastQuestion.nextQuestion neq "">
        <!--- Ok, we definitely need to go someplace else. But do we have to have an answer? --->       
        <cfif lastQuestion.nextQuestionValue eq "">
            <!--- In this branch, we ALWAYS go to another q --->
            <cfset questionToLoad = application.question.getQuestion(lastQuestion.nextQuestion)>
            <cfset currentInfo.currentStep = questionToLoad.rank>
        <cfelse>
            <cfset answer = currentInfo.answers[lastQuestion.id]>
            <cfset theanswermatches = false>
            <!--- first do a simple check - assumes answer is simple --->
            <cfif isSimpleValue(answer) and answer is lastQuestion.nextQuestionValue>
                <cfset theAnswerMatches = true>
            </cfif>
            <!--- next support our MC with a .list key --->
            <cfif isStruct(answer) and structKeyExists(answer,"list") and listFind(answer.list, lastQuestion.nextQuestionValue)>
                <cfset theAnswerMatches = true>
            </cfif> 
            <cfif theanswermatches>
                <cfset questionToLoad = application.question.getQuestion(lastQuestion.nextQuestion)>
                <cfset currentInfo.currentStep = questionToLoad.rank>
            <cfelse>
                <cfset currentInfo.currentStep = currentInfo.currentStep + 1>
            </cfif>

            </cfif>
        </cfif>
    <cfelse>
        <cfset currentInfo.currentStep = currentInfo.currentStep + 1>
    </cfif>
    <cflocation url="#cgi.script_name#?#cgi.query_string#" addToken="false">
</cfif>
```

Above  code works fine but I am trying to add a condition for it to work this way. 
Where you have italics, it  goes to next question if answer matches. I want to add condition where if questionfilter ="ifnot" then

```
<cfif theanswermatches>
                <cfset questionToLoad = application.question.getQuestion(lastQuestion.nextQuestion)>
                <cfset currentInfo.currentStep = questionToLoad.rank>
            <cfelse>
                <cfset currentInfo.currentStep = currentInfo.currentStep + 1>
            </cfif>
```

changes to

```
            <cfif theanswermatches>
                <cfset currentInfo.currentStep = currentInfo.currentStep + 1>
            <cfelse>
                <cfset questionToLoad = application.question.getQuestion(lastQuestion.nextQuestion)>
                <cfset currentInfo.currentStep = questionToLoad.rank>
            </cfif>
```

Each time I try to add the condition, the whole application ends the survey in eithr condition of the survey. I suspect the  code is not getting the value for the  questionfilter, How can  I get this and and  also confirm  what I am getting.

Currently what I do is

```
 <cfif lastQuestion.questionfilter eq "">
```

All suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: That's a lot of code to muddle through but one thing looks bad.  In your first function, you appear to be referring to variables from the calling page.

Comment: Thanks Dan. Its actually an existing survey application. The only thing I added "questionfilter" to retrieve the value for that column.  I dont know if I did it right or if there is a better way of achieving thins.  The original code is without that filed - questionfilter.